# PostgreSQL serialize data as in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, serialization

In my database,  I've got a field where are stored data `serialized` in `PHP` by serialize() function.

I have to prepare a function in PostgreSQL that inserts data into this field, so it is required to serialize the data before the insert. Is in pgSQL any equivalent function to PHP `serialize()`?

Comment: Whoops. Don't double down on a bad design. You'll need to fix this by changing the way the data is stored in PostgreSQL into something saner. `json` might be an option if you cannot normalize it.

Comment: I know that it is not correct way but I want to limit number of requests to database and don't want to change all system. This is the new one feature and I want to made all operations on database side but I must use current db architecture.

Comment: Then you're in trouble. Your best hope is probably https://github.com/commandprompt/PL-php. It looks inactive, but it should probably still work. I really think you are making a big mistake, and should fix the database design. It will be painful, but you're going to have to do it sooner or later. If you use `json` or similar you can still reduce round-trips.

Comment: I agree with Craig: you shouldn't do that. Your justification to obfuscate the data in the database (which is what you are doing by storing a serialized object) is a moot one. It _will_ give you a lot of problems in the long run - without actually giving you any benefit. If you really, really think it's the right way, you should rather store the data as JSON or JSONB. You have full SQL support on the Postgres side and although I don't know PHP you should be able to handle JSON easily in PHP as well.

Comment: I do agree with you all but I don't have possibility to remodel the database because I am not its administrator. There is a lot of to do but it is not in my competencies, I have only to add one feature using existing tables. Thanks for all your help, I will try to write own function in psql to serialize the data.